# How to install numpy, scipy, and other packages from source for Python3 in Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS

Tags: install-from-source, python3, matplotlib, numpy

I just recently installed Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS alongside Windows-7 (64-bit).  I wanted to install the latest versions of numpy, scipy, matplotlib, and other packages for Python3.  I saw the we can use `sudo apt-get install python3-numpy python3-scipy`, but the Ubuntu software center does not contain the latest versions of numpy, scipy, etc.

Can somebody point me to a tutorial to install the latest version of these packages from the source in Ubuntu?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This](http://cwl.cx/posts/building-scipy-on-ubuntu-1204.html) should do the deal. Building both numpy and scipy from git repository. About upgrading matplotlib you can read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22104764/can-not-upgrade-matplotlib-to-1-3-1)

Comment: How do I make sure I install numpy and scipy specifically for Python3.4 and not for Python2.7.x?  Should I replace Python with Python3 wherever it is used?

Comment: If you install direct from git it should be up to date version supporting Python 3.4 according to its documentation [link](http://matplotlib.org/users/installing.html)

Comment: Hi,  I followed the steps outlink in the link you sent for installing numpy and scipy from git.  All the process went fine.  However, when I try import numpy as np and then np.__version__, I get the following error: **AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute '__version__'**.  The same happens for scipy.  Further, none of the subroutines of the numpy, such as numpy.arange works.  Although I didn't see any error during installation, is it possible that the packages didn't install correctly?

Comment: How did you try to print out the version? Via script or command line? 'import numpy'
>> 'print numpy.__version__'?

Comment: when I tried dir(numpy), __version__ is not one of the attributes? Also, numpy.arange doesn't work either?  It's just not installed correctly in my belief.

Comment: Hi, I found the problem.  The numpy and scipy packages are actually installed under Python2.7.x and not under Python3.4.x, which I what I am interested in.  Is there a way to specify where to install the packages before hand.  Thanks for your help in advance.